# Deleting items in back end & trash manager

Tags: joomla-3.x, administration

Just been doing a bit of housekeeping on a few of my sites (Joomla 3.x) and this feature has been (slightly) annoying me.

Basically whenever I delete an article or item from the back end of my site, it firstly goes into the trash. I then have to go into the trash and empty it. Not a huge issue, many may see this as a benefit. However I feel that a one click 'delete' solution would be beneficial. Currently it adds an extra step to an already tedious process.

I was having the same issue when deleting some categories and menu items. I was unable to re-create categories and menu items with the same name because on already existed - but where? The trash. Once the trash was emptied it was fine again.

If anybody has suggestions on how to implement such a feature I would be most interested, or if I am missing something and have been using Joomla incorrectly all this time please do tell.

Hope this makes sense to somebody.

Comment: Having looked around, the only extension I've seen that **might** have this feature is [this](http://jextbox.com/jextbox-article-auto-manager.html). If this doesn't do the trick then you could create a script and a cron job to execute it or a plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking around and the only extension that I came across which I believe will have this functionality is [JExtBOX](http://jextbox.com/jextbox-article-auto-manager.html).

An alternative would be to create a script (placed in the CLI directory) that deletes items from the trash which could then be executed by a cron job every X amount of hours, days etc.